# finding user on aws cognito throws error cognitoidentityserviceprovider is not defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS services and I am trying out various services provided by AWS. I have this lambda function on which I am trying to find a user with the phone number on AWS Cognito -

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
async function findCognitoUser(userId) {
    console.log('CognitoUser-FindCognitoUser');    
    var params = {
            UserPoolId: 'poolId',
            AttributesToGet: [
            'phone_number','displayName'
        ],
        Filter: `phone_number = \"${userId}\"`,
    };
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return 'ERROR OCCURED';
    }
    else     {
      return data.Users[0].displayName;
    }
    });
 }
 module.exports = findCognitoUser;
```

I do get an error saying **cognitoidentityserviceprovider is not defined**

Here is the error on CloudWatch -

```
"errorType": "ReferenceError",
    "errorMessage": "cognitoidentityserviceprovider is not defined",
    "stack": [
        "ReferenceError: cognitoidentityserviceprovider is not defined",
        "    at findCognitoUser (/var/task/user-queries/findCognitoUser.js:13:5)",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:14:19)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
```

CODE UPDATED -

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

async function findCognitoUser(userId) {
    console.log(userId);
    var csp = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});
    var params = {
            UserPoolId: 'poolid',
            AttributesToGet: [
            'phone_number','given_name'
        ],
        Filter: `phone_number = \"${userId}\"`,
        
    };
    csp.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);
    if (err) {
      return 'ERROR OCCURED';
    }
    else     {
      return data.Users[0].given_name;
    }
    });
 }
 module.exports = findCognitoUser;
```

Comment: This looks to be a programming error rather than an AWS service error. You haven't defined 'cognitoidentityserviceprovider' before calling listusers with it.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad I have updated the code on the post, this time I dont get any errors, but it doesn't return anything. It should be returning on item which has the phone number starting with +14160000000.

Comment: Do you mean console.log(data) is printing nothing? Can you console.log a static string before it to make sure the code is reaching that point?